Power BI Time Taken
I'm having some trouble calculating the total run time for these. I can get somewhere near using the DIFFDATE calculation but I can only get minutes or hours and not both -  and sometimes because of the time format I get a minus number too? Would love some help to get the run time in hh:mm:ss -thanks

I've tried using the DIFFDATE calculation but can't get what I need

you can try this
Column = 'Table'[RunStart - Date]+'Table'[RunStart-Time]-('Table'[RunEnd - Date]+'Table'[RunEnd-Time])

and set the new column to time type. Then I think you will get the result of hh:mm:ss


I do that but then I get the column like this and it's all just incorrect and negative numbers then when changing it from number to time it just says error

it looks like the start time and finish time columns are text type. Pls try to change these two column to time type.

Hiya, they are time type

I missed your date column. I have updated the solution. pls have a try
